# Output first day of year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have various needs for time calculations, but can't get the basic syntax right.  The measure

```
First Day of Year = STARTOFYEAR('Calendar'[Date])
```

returns 1/1/2019, which is the earliest date on my calendar table.  Today's date being Jun 2022, I want it to return 1/1/2022.

Related question:  In order to return the first day of the fiscal year (October 1 of the prior year) I would expect something like

```
First Day of Fiscal Year = STARTOFYEAR(DATEADD('Calendar'[Date],-3,MONTH))
```

But this returns the same result, 1/1/2019.  Desired result is 10/1/2021

Answer (score 0):

If you want it reference **this** *(the current)* year, you need the `TODAY()` function.

eg:

```
First Day of Year = date(year(TODAY()),1,1)
First Day of Fiscal Year = date(year(today())-1,10,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the first Date of the year of a table containing more Years you have to filter the date Table:

```
CALCULATETABLE(STARTOFYEAR('Calendar'[Date]), 'Calendar'[Year]=year(today()))
```